# AngularJS - make the dropdown option with selected attribute the default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select like:

```
<select ng-model="formData.num" id="num" name="num">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I can make angular choose 2 as the default by having the following in my controller:

```
$scope.formData.num = 2;
```

But how do I make it automatically select the option element with the selected attribute, rather than hard coding 2 in my controller?

Comment: Why do you need to use angular? :) You are probably missing the point.. You can just remove the ng-model and use the select as is... Or use ng-selected="true" instead of selected="selected", it won't set the ng-model though. Or go against the specs and use `ng-init="formData.num=2"` which is again hardcoding in the view.. So in short setting it in the controller is the right way IMO.

Comment: @PSL I use angular all over the page, including the rest of my form and submitting the form. So the reason the select element is utilising angular, it's because I need the ng-model binding.

Comment: As i said in the prev comment, using angular and using it the right way is different.. :) Sorry.. That is just my opinion.. It is upto you. I have mentioned the options you have in the previous comment, thats all i know. Take a look at using ng-options as well.

Comment: Agree with @PSL. Plus, I think putting `selected` attribute on a particular `<option>` is another form of hard-coding. Not so sure about your concern in the question. Is it code comprehensibility that you are worried about? If I were to suggest, forget about the `selected` attribute and come up with better comments and/or variable names in your controller. As an example, `var default_num = 2; $scope.formData.num = default_num;`